Reading data from RS232c device
Mechanical engineer here beginner to the world of coding and software development.
I have a digital dial indicator that has a RS232c data communication port. The device product page mentions the port as OPTO RS232C. After a quick search I understand it is a optical isolation to prevent ground loops.
I want to be able to read the output of the device real time(ish). Goal is to implement a closed loop control of a stepper motor once I can figure out how to read the data from the device.
The device comes with a Serial to USB adapter and a software that connects to the gage.
The problem is the update rate is slow. 10 data update every second. Not sure if this is the limit of the software or RS232 itself. I have updated the com port settings to have 1ms latency and max bit rate and max bits transfer.
Is there a way I can use command prompt or windows shell to communicate with the device provided I have the drivers installed?
I would like to read the data from this device in windows first and then move on to a suitable microcontroller as a next step.
I can open up the device to look at what microcontroller is present if needed and any other information requested.
FYI- The device is MAHR 1086Ri
Link - https://metrology.mahr.com/en-int/products/article/4337134-1086-ri-digitale-messuhr-125mm-5-zw-001mm/
I have tried searching for commands to communicate with RS232. So far no luck since I cannot install softwares on my work laptop. Waiting for IT to issue a temp laptop to install any software I need for development.
I am willing to try suggestions/advice on my personal laptop to learn coding and development.
Expecting advice on good starting point on communicating with RS232c device.
All info online has 9 pins on RS232 ports. I only have 4 pins on my device.
Thank you,
Tejas

Update:
i understand I need to use C or Python or similar to communicate with the device. Once I am able to communicate I also need to create a simple UI to show the data being collected. So need advice on which is better Python or C? or is there a better language? I would like to start in a language that will be preferred for the UI design.
Thanks!

"All info online has 9 pins on RS232 ports" - Because they are referring to the (modern) convention of using a 9-pin DB9 connector. "I only have 4 pins on my device" - What kind of connector? What signals are on those pins? A minimal RS232 connection only needs three signals: RxD, TxD, and GND.

@sawdust The device has 4 pin out put. The manufacturer also sells a USB cable to attach the device to PC. I am not sure how to add pictures while replying. If you search on google for SPC data cable MAHR, there are plenty of pictures that show the connector. https://www.cdiweb.com/manufacturer/mahr/data-management/spc-connecting-cable . This link should help. The manufacturer sells cables that have 4 pin to standard 9 pin serial port and some other types of connectors as well. I am not sure what the 4 pins do. But the USB end has a serial to USB connector. The device shows up as a COM PORT.

@sawdust https://www.microridge.com/products/interface-cable-w-mahr-federal-caliper-data-send/ this link might be better to look at the connector.
